# PYTHON TKINTER How to check if Button Exists, delete if it does and carry on if not?

Tags: python, tkinter

I am creating a quiz app.
Once logged in, the user is presented with a home screen which is created
in a function.
On completion of a quiz, there is an end screen (created in another function) with the option to take another quiz which will take the user back to the home screen.

**What I am trying to do is delete the end screen buttons & labels within the home screen function if labels/buttons created in the end screen function exist.**

Simplified version of the code I am trying to run.

```
from tkinter import *

def homeScreen():
    global endtext, againbutton
    if endtext.winfo_exists() == 1:
        endtext.destroy()
        againbutton.destroy()

    successlogin=label(window, text=("You are logged in as: " + Username))
    successlogin.grid(column=1, row=4)
    global startquiz
    startquiz=Button(window, text="Start Quiz", command=quiz)
    startquiz.grid(column=1, row=4)

def quiz():
    global startquiz
    startquiz.destroy()

    #Display questions and check answers etc. etc.

    endscreen() #On completion of quiz

def endScreen():
    global endtext, againbutton
    endtext=Label(window, text="quiz complete")
    endtext.grid(column=1, row=1)
    againbutton=Button(window, text="again", command=homescreen)
    againbutton.grid(column=1, row=2)

window=Tk()
window.mainloop()

homeScreen()
```

I have tried to do this by using endtext.winfo_exists() but I get a name error saying endtext isn't defined. Even just putting

```
print(endtext.winfo_exists())
```

results in the name error.

When againbutton is pressed, homescreen() is called but the endtext and againbutton stay on the window getting in the way of the other labels and buttons.

Note how {startquiz} is created in one function but deleted in the next. My intention is for everything created in {endscreen()} to be deleted IF the user presses {againbutton} The issue I think being that because on the first run through, the code is trying to delete something that has not been declared. That is why I am checking to see if it exists and have so far been unsuccessful in doing this

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] for better answer(s).

Comment: What do you mean not declared? If you mean not positioned (endtext.grid(...)) I have done that but for the purpose of simplifying the question, I left it out

Comment: I'm aware the exact code above wouldn't work. I have tried to simplify the code as I have lots of other code which is irrelevant to my question. I have tried to add some more code which may make my intentions more obvious.

Comment: Note how {startquiz} is created in one function but deleted in the next. My intention is for everything created in {endscreen()}  to be deleted IF the user presses {againbutton} The issue I think being that because on the first run through, the code is trying to delete something that has not been declared. That is why I am checking to see if it exists and have so far been unsuccessful in doing this. @Nae

Comment: _"I'm aware the exact code above wouldn't work."_ should never be the case unless above code not working is _the issue_ to be resolved.

Comment: Added 3 lines which would make it work. The code above now gives you the name error described. Clearly I simplified the code too much. I have now solved the issue anyway through use of another function as seen in my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that `endtext`and `againbutton` are not declared on the first call of `homeScreen()`
Add this function below `endscreen()` to delete the attributes.

```
def clearEnd():
    global endtext, againbutton

    endtext.destroy()
    againbutton.destroy()

    homescreen()
```

To give:

```
from tkinter import *

def homeScreen()
    successlogin=label(window, text=("You are logged in as: " + Username)
    global startquiz
    startquiz=Button(window, text="Start Quiz", command=quiz)
    startquiz.grid(column=1, row=4)

def quiz():
    global startquiz
    startquiz.destroy()

    #Display questions and check answers etc. etc.

    endscreen() #On completion of quiz

def endScreen()
    global endtext, againbutton
    endtext=Label(window, text="quiz complete")
    endtext.grid(column=1, row=1)
    againbutton=Button(window, text="again", command=homescreen)
    againbutton.grid(column=1, row=2)

def clearEnd():
    global endtext, againbutton

    endtext.destroy()
    againbutton.destroy()

    homescreen()
```

Answer (score 1):

Assert:

```
endtext = tkinter.Label(...)
```

and:

```
againbutton = tkinter.Button(...)
```

Then a simple:

```
if endtext:
```

or:

```
if againbutton:
```

should suffice as they are non-empty *objects* declared in an accessible scope, in this case, *global* scope.